# Drawer is "eating" parts of the screen label. How to solve?

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I am developing a drawer for navigation between screens of my application. I have a Home screen, which label is "Home", when compiling the application Drawer only displays "Hom" instead of displaying the full name (Home)

Environment:

- react-native 0.60
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-navigation: 3

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  DrawerItems
} from 'react-navigation';

import { HomeScreen, HomeLogin } from './src/screens';

const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const App = () => {
  return <Apps />;
};
const CustomDrawerComponent = props => (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ScrollView>
      <View
        style={{
          height: 180,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center'
        }}
      >
        <Image
          source={require('./src/assets/nologin-user.png')}
          style={{ height: 150, width: 150, borderRadius: 75 }}
        />
      </View>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
);

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(

  {
    Home:{
      screen:HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions:{
      drawerLabel:'Home',
      },

    }
  },    
  {
    drawerWidth: DEVICE_WIDTH - 100,
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent,
    contentOptions:{
      activeTintColor:'#006bb3',
      labelStyle:{
        fontSize:13,

      },

    }
  }
);
const Apps = createAppContainer(AppDrawerNavigator);

export default App;
```

I expected the drawer to display "Home" not "Hom"

Problem
[image]

Comment: Does changing the drawerWidth help?

Comment: No, if I change, just continue with "Hom"

Comment: Seems like that is actually a common problem: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3389

Comment: AHHHH BROOOO.
I am using OnePlus 5 with OnePlus font. For some reason the drawer conflicts with the font I use. Thanks for sending me the post link !! If you had not seen it would be trying until you can!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the source of the phone. If you use an Oppo smartphone to emulate and are experiencing this error try using the native android font.